# HTML/CSS: My Mini-Chat is overflowing in IE

Tags: html, css, browser, internet-explorer, compatibility

So here's another IE cross-compatibility issue. My website, www.zerozaku.com, is compatible with Chrome and Firefox, but IE has an issue with my Mini-Chat overflowing out of the box. Could anyone help?

P.S. I've only tested it on IE8, Firefox, Chrome

Comment: GIGO: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zerozaku.com&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: I get this error from IE:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Timestamp: Tue, 16 Feb 2010 11:59:09 UTC


Message: Expected identifier, string or number
Line: 24
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: http://www.zerozaku.com/styles/zerozaku/template/default.js

Comment: As @David says, get your HTML straight first. Not correctly closed tags are one of the main causes for overflowing boxes.

Comment: My XHTML is cleaner now, but none of these errors had any real correlation with my Mini-Chat and why it's not specifically compatible with IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just restructured the XHTML and CSS to be IE-compliant.

Answer (score 1):

First error on list `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">`
needs a closing tag like `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />`

Also if you try to run the validator on your page you'll notice that you have 50+ markup errors which I bet are causing missbehaviour in IE.

Comment: I have now successfully, completely validated the index.html page. Nothing happened except that my code now looks more professional.

Comment: Nothing changed, but atleast now we can start debugging properly, since we know there are no markup errors.

#mChatData .body {
float:left;
margin-top:-39px;
width:100%;
}

Remove width and top margin from that class. Set an overflow:hidden on the div that is the container for .avatar and .body and adjust .body style so it will look nice again (remove margin-left etc) and it should work in IE. Like it is done now it's not really a best practice.